# ENOENT: no such file or directory. Replit

Tags: node.js, fs

I have been coding a bot in replit using node.js and when I try to run it I get this error:

```
internal/fs/utils.js:269
    throw err;
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/runner/musicjs/index.js'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:462:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:364:35)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/run_dir/interp.js:195:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  errno: -2,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'ENOENT',


    path: '/home/runner/musicjs/index.js'

}
```

Any ideas why its giving me this error?

Here's some screenshots:
[image: Full screen]
[image: Files]
[image: package.json]
[image: Console]

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Well what does your file system look like?

Comment: Can you add some screenshots so we can see where file you are looking for located and where script you are running located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a .replit file and it now works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).